# mouseMoved event stopping when mouse is down

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, nib, mouseup

I have implemented a custom NSView (marked as ) and am able to get mouseUp:, mouseDown: and mouseMoved: events. To this I have acceptsFirstResponder returning YES, and also call the following in awakeFromNib:

```
[[self window] makeFirstResponder:self];
[[self window] seAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:true];
```

However the extremely strange thing is that if I click and drag, the mouseMoved: events stop coming in until I let go of the mouse button and get a mouseUp:

I have seen other related posts, but they all say that if the view is first responder (and it is), then I should be receiving these events.

Why is the mousemoved: event stopping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-(void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event
```

is called instead of

```
-(void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)event
```

when the left mouse button is down. So if you have anything you need to do in both cases, call a common method to do it from both of these.

Comment: Thanks, what a definitive and simple answer! I wish all questions had answers this nice (: